# for loop causing multiple creation of object

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have an array containing messages that I print to the screen randomly one at a time. I am using javascript to create a new DOM element ('p') and then to create a new text node that I attach to the new p element.

In order to not display a duplicate, I created a new array that will hold the new text that is displayed. Prior to printing to the screen, I check to make sure that the text that is about to be displayed is not currently in the new array so that I can check for duplicates.

It is never finding a duplicate however because each time it goes through the for loop it is creating another object (I believe it is a text node because each iteration through it will console log me the text nodes content +=1 each time. For instance, the first time might get:

"this is the message"

and the next console log I will get:

"this is the message"
"this is the message"

and the next time:

"this is the message"
"this is the message"
"this is the message"

Here is the code I am using for that portion as I believe this is the only relevant code:

```
function randomMessages(){
    var displayMessage = document.getElementById('front-message');
    var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    newParagraph.setAttribute('class', 'front-page-messages');
    currentMessage = Math.floor(Math.random() * frontPageMessages.length);
    var randomText = document.createTextNode(frontPageMessages[currentMessage]);
    checkPastMessages(oldMessages, randomText, newParagraph); // check new array containing displayed messages for duplicates
    newParagraph.appendChild(randomText);
    displayMessage.appendChild(newParagraph);
    newParagraph.style.position = "relative";
    newParagraph.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerHeight -430) ) + "px";
    newParagraph.style.textAlign = "center";
    newParagraph.style.fontFamily ="'Montserrat', sans-serif";
    newParagraph.style.fontSize = "1.3em";
    newParagraph.style.color = "#52A8EC";
    oldMessages.push(randomText);
    console.log(oldMessages);
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        displayMessage.removeChild(newParagraph);
        newParagraph.removeChild(randomText);
        randomMessages();
    }, 5000);
}
randomMessages();

function checkPastMessages(oldMessages, randomText, newParagraph){
    for(var i = 0; i < oldMessages.length; i++){
        if(randomText == oldMessages[i]){
            console.log('duplicate');
            randomMessages();
        }else{
            console.log('not a duplicate');
            console.log(randomText);
        };

    };

}
```

Comment: Whenever your `checkPastMessages()` script finds a duplicate, it starts up a new `randomMessages()` cycle. I don't understand why.

Comment: The intention was to rerun randomMessages() if the array already contained the text, but I see in doing so I am creating more objects because I have not removed them. I still need to figure out how to do that without deleting the element before it is used in the event it is not a duplicate. (edit - I just added the remove elements to the in the event a duplicate is found but my original problem still exists.)

Comment: Text nodes are objects, which are compared by reference. You should instead compare their `nodeValue`s, or store the used indices (`currentMessage`).

Comment: You could also order your messages randomly up front, and then just 'pop' one off the list every 5 seconds.

Comment: Btw, what should happen when all messages from array are displayed, reset all, and start new cycle?

Comment: I am going to try and pop it off the array and once that length = 0 I am going to have it equal the old array so it starts over. I am in school right now so when something doesn't work as intended I still like to understand why so I can know for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
change line: checkPastMessages(oldMessages, randomText, newParagraph)
to:  checkPastMessages(oldMessages, randomText.textContent, newParagraph)
```

and

```
change line: oldMessages.push(randomText)
to: oldMessages.push(randomText.textContent)
```

this way the following line would be comparing string literals as opposed to objects:

```
if(randomText == oldMessages[i]) {
```

you won't get equality between two objects comparison.  Try the following examples in a console:

```
var o=document.createTextNode("abc");
var b=document.createTextNode("abc");

console.log(o==b); //should yield false;
console.log(o.textContent==b.textContent); //should yield true

var c = o;
console.log(c == o); //should yield true since they both point to the same object address (reference).
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the string `frontPageMessages[currentMessage]` or the index `currentMessage` to the list `oldMessages`.

It currently doesn't work because the object comparison in `checkPastMessages` doesn't see the identical nodes as identical. What adds to the confusion is that `console.log` treats text nodes as if they were strings.